# how to compare hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two `HashMaps` and i want to compare the keys of the values and if they are different return the difference between both keys

```
public class AsciiCount {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "Hello";
        String input1 = "eHllo";
        
        Store obj1= new Store();
        
        String orderOfString = obj1.CheckOrder(input);
        System.out.println(orderOfString);
        
        HashMap inputLocation = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input);
        HashMap input1Location = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input1);
        System.out.println(inputLocation);
        System.out.println(input1Location);
    }
}
// OUTPUT of print
// inputLocation = {0=72, 1=101, 2=108, 3=108, 4=111}
// input1Location = {0=101, 1=72, 2=108, 3=108, 4=111}
```

**Example**

Here

Key of 72 is 0 in `inputLocation` but key of 72 is 1 in `input1Location`

Key of 101 is 1 in `inputLocation` but key of 101 is 0 in `input1Location`

So output should be `2` ( i.e no. of changes )

Comment: For your particular case, how about looping over the keys and adding them to a new hashmap with the difference ? Like `result.put( key, inputLocation.get(key) - input1Location.get(key))`

Comment: @BlackPearl Can you please put it as a complete answer ? it looks okay..

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the problem. Can you provide a required sample output? Is the output in the form of a map?

Comment: I have provided the output in the question under `Example` its in the form of an integer

Comment: Here, both the keys of 72 and 101 have changed. Is there any reason for checking only 72 here?

Comment: @BlackPearl My Bad,101 will be checked aswell i will update the question thanks

Comment: @Phil Is map have duplicate values ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks No since my key is index of a byte array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what is needed is the count of values which have changed, this code should work.

```
HashMap inputLocation = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input);
HashMap input1Location = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input1);
int diffCount = 0;
for (Object key : inputLocation.keySet()) {
     if ( !inputLocation.get(key).equals(input1Location.get(key))){
         diffCount++;           
     }
}
```

diffCount will give you the count of changed values.

This is just some rough code, please feel free to update it. I advice you to use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` instead of a plain `HashMap`, as that guarantees type saftey.

Comment: what is `abcd.keySet()` do i need to define this somewhere ?

Comment: @Phil `keySet` is a standard method of `Map`, see [Map.keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equals on the keySet() of both objects HashMaps to compare a single value. With this you can compare/obtain the key param of the Hash. After this you have to get the value of the HashMap to compare the value. But if you need to compare the entire hash just use equals.

Your code it will look like this:

```
public class AsciiCount {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "Hello";
    String input1 = "eHllo";
    
    Store obj1= new Store();
    
    String orderOfString = obj1.CheckOrder(input);
    System.out.println(orderOfString);
    HashMap inputLocation = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input);
    HashMap input1Location = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input1);
    System.out.println(inputLocation);
    System.out.println(input1Location);
    HashMap input1Location = obj1.getCharacterLocation(input1);

    // This is the comparison of the value from the key
    inputLocation.get(inputLocation.keySet()[2]).equals(input1Location.get(input1Location.keySet()[2]);
    // 2 is the second argument of the key value in the HashMap

    // This is the comparison of the two hashes
    inputLocation.equals(input1Location);

    // OUTPUT of print
    // inputLocation = {0=72, 1=101, 2=108, 3=108, 4=111}
    // input1Location = {0=101, 1=72, 2=108, 3=108, 4=111}
    // true
    // false


}}
```

Comment: can you please provide a more complete code snippet ?

Comment: I rephrased the answer

Comment: This is throwing an error :( 

`The method get(int) is undefined for the type Set`

Comment: try to change to the get(2), to [2]